# Specman-e usage of try { };

Tags: try-catch, unpack, specman

I would like to know what the keyword `try` is used for in Specman and especially its usage in the code snippet given below:

```
try {
    unpack(packing.low,lob,pkt);
} else{
    message(LOW, “Uh-oh!”){print lob using HEX;};
    message(LOW,”bad unpack!!!”);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try` and `else` are Specman's [exception handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) constructs.  If an error is created in the `try` [block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28programming%29), then the `else` block is immediately executed instead of the rest of the `try` block and the error is suppressed with *no printout*.

In this case, if `lob` has more bits than `pkt` has "physical fields", then the unpack will generate an error.  If that happens, the Specman runtime will jump to the `else` block and print out the `lob` data structure instead of printing the original `unpack` error.  Look in the docs with regards to what "physical fields" are and how they are used.  They are a strange construct that specifically interacts with the behavior of Specman's `%`, `pack`, and `unpack` constructs.  Physical fields of `pkt` will be declared with the `%` modifier preceding the "physical fields" of `pkt`.

Answer (score 1):

try and if are similar where if executes the true block when the condition is true
and else it executes the false.
similarly try also if there is an error in the true block it switches to else block.